# How to download a csv file from SharePoint by using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to download a file from SharePoint and save it into a local folder.

I get a timeout error or Automation error.

```vb
Sub CSVDownload()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Output As String
    Dim HttpReq As Object
    
    ' URL of File in SharePoint
    URL = "https://myenterprisename.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/Projects/EWDlWrHMVHVCnDNTuV9xY7MBUwtm0QCTwAEoQsqQNVbYzA?e=hrgiOr"
    
    ' Local Path
    Output = "C:\Users\Desktop\test\LocalFile.csv"
    
    ' HTTPRequest
    Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    
    ' Get Request
    HttpReq.Open "GET", URL, False
    HttpReq.send
    
    ' Verifiying if Request was succesfull
    If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        ' Saving file into local file
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(Destino, True)
        a.Write HttpReq.responseText
        a.Close
        MsgBox "File Downloaded"
    Else
        MsgBox "Something went wrong: " & HttpReq.Status
    End If
    
    Set HttpReq = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note 1: I'm not pretty sure if the URL I'm using is the proper one, here is how I get it.**
[image]

**Note 2: Since this macro is going to be executed automatically in a server as batch, it is not an option to use auto-sync Excel functionality or similar.**

Answer (score -1):

You can configure synchronization with local folder (Use "Synchronize" button on the toolbar), and open the local file instead. You do not need VBA to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry this is not an option, the macro is going to executed in a server like a batch. I add this note in the post.

Comment: Hmm how do you plan to execute a VBA macro on a server? Server-side automation of the office applications not supported, as far as I know? If you want to do it server-side, then you could use something more appropriate for the task than vba...

Comment: ok then, I'll wait for another suggestion.

Comment: Okay then. BTW, what you are doing wrong here - you need to authenticate with SharePoint, i.e. you are trying to download the file anonymously. Good luck doing taht with VBA on the server :)

Comment: I already figured it out in VBA and it works perfectly :)

Comment: You can post the solution here then maybe (answer your own question), i.e. what worked for you, for others to learn